# Spring boot application that run service in sequential order by passing the sequence at the run time

Tags: spring-boot

I want to implement a spring boot application that have 3 services . Now I want to run 3 services from my controller sequentially . I want to pass the the name of service and method as well as input parameters and sequence through controller and want to get the result of each of service . Please let me know how I can achieve these with a simple spring boot application.

Comment: "I want to run 3 services..", "I want to pass the the name of service and method...", "want to get the result of each of service..." - could you please clarify what exactly do you want and what do you have problem with.

Comment: I have several util implementation like load data from file , do some validation, write the output in file etc. I want to make a flow where user will pass the service name , method name , sequences and all the input parameter. System will execute all the service method as per sequence and send the output and status of each of process to controller. In the screen I want to see the status of every process at run time.

Comment: Is it possible to do with spring work flow ??

Answer (score 0):

Very very high level example. General idea that you need to use "reflection" for create class instance by name and/or call methods dynamically without "if". Pay attention that code can be different if your "service" is spring bean.

```
interface Service {
    void method();
}

class Service1 implements Service {

    @Override
    public void method() {
        // do magic
    }
}

class Service2 implements Service {

    @Override
    public void method() {
        // do magic
    }
}


class Test {

    public void executeMe(String className, String methodName) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {

        // you may need to have full class name with package
        Service service = (Service) Class.forName(className).newInstance();

        if ("method".equalsIgnoreCase(methodName)) {
            service.method();
        }

    }

}
```

---

**Update**

```
class Service1 {
    public void method1() {
        // do magic
    }

    public void method2() {
        // do magic
    }
}

class Service2 {
    public void method3() {
        // do magic
    }
}

class Test {

    public void executeMe(String className, String methodName) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {

        // you may need to have full class name with package
        Service1 service = (Service1) Class.forName(className).newInstance();

        if ("method1".equalsIgnoreCase(methodName)) {
            service.method1();
        }

    }
}
```

with Spring

```
class Test {

    @Autowired
    private Service1 service1;

    @Autowired
    private Service2 service2;

    public void executeMe(String className, String methodName) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("service1", service1);
        map.put("service2", service2);

        // you may need to have full class name with package
        if ("service1".equalsIgnoreCase(className)) {
            Service1 service1 = (Service1) map.get(className);

            if ("method1".equalsIgnoreCase(methodName)) {
                service1.method1();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Again, this is very very high level meta code.

Comment: Is there any framework in spring that can handle this. Also there is an problem in this design that , I have to mention all the method in Service interface. That I do not want to do also I do not want to use reflection as well . I want a controller method that pass an list of map. Each map will contain service name , method name, all the parameters . There will be a handler that will handle the list of map and call service one by one and send the output to controller on each steps.

Comment: Thanks ... but I am looking for spring orchestration or activity framework as in future I may have 100 service.

Comment: May be I understood you wrong. Can you clarify why my example is not valid? You have map of spring beans, you can find your service by name, call method you need, pass parameters.

Comment: Your example is valid but I have looking for a framework like spring integration  or activity. Also need to check whether I could avoid the if conditions

Comment: If you want to use "integration" or "activiti" then you need to mention that in your question. My code was "meta" abstract code and of course you can avoid "if" conditions and map.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Is there any way to get the status and output of each service at runtime . In current design all the services will behave a single service and difficult to get the status of individual service at run time.